# Instagram Api login only working on iOs simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, instagram-api

After spending one day in google and stackOverflow testing every way to log in to instagram vía my own app, I'm almost sure I've tried everything but nothing worked.

I've downloaded [instaAuth](https://github.com/davidseek/InstaAuth) and tried it in my iOs 11 device. I get on screen error:

```
{"error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "code":403, "error_message", "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}
```

I'm testing with the only cliend ID that I have and the user is the admin.

In the log, I get a different error:

```
InstaAuth[3870:1257213] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process InstaAuth
2017-11-21 14:54:03.815613+0100 InstaAuth[3870:1257213] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2017-11-21 14:54:03.815717+0100 InstaAuth[3870:1257213] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

I've tested the same code in the simulator (iphone 7+ iOs 10.2 and iphone 7+ iOs 11.1) and it worked (¿?!), the login screen appeared, I have been able to log-in and get the instagram token.

I've been looking at other posts that have the same error than my console log, but haven't found a solution for my problem. What I don't understand is how it can works in simulator and not in the device.
Any help would be appreciated

**edit:** with this code below I can open the url and even get the instagram token:

```
let instagramURL : URL = URL.init(string: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id="+CInstagram.clientId+"&redirect_uri="+CInstagram.redirectUri+"&response_type=token")!

            if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL))
            {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(instagramURL)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
```

The browser goes to instagram, and the url appears with the token, the only problem is I can't get this token back to my app because, when the user press the back button to go to my app, there is not any delegate method called with the final url and the token.

Vía webView, it throws me the same error **(WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO)** but never ends in the final url with the token.

The only way I managed to get into the final url is opening it vía `UIApplication.shared.open(instagramUrl)` 
but it seems there is no way to get a return value to my app because the instagram uri only let me put an url with http or https but not with a mobile format (exampleApp://) so my app is not called back.

Comment: Did you found any solutions for the same?

Comment: Sorry didn't seen this comment until now. Yes I finally managed to solve it. The problem were I was supposed to accept the user sandbox invitation from the invited account but instead of this, I had to do "accept it" from the Instagram admin account. Once I did that, it worked